# Customized hash function for Python

Tags: python, hash

I would like to generate a human-readable hash with customized properties -- e.g., a short string of specified length consisting entirely of upper case letters and digits excluding 0, 1, O, and I (to eliminate visual ambiguity):

```
"arbitrary string"  -->  "E3Y7UM8"
```

A 7-character string of the above form could take on over 34 billion unique values which, for my purposes, makes collisions extremely unlikely.  Security is also not a major concern.

Is there an existing module or routine that implements something like the above? Alternatively, can someone suggest a straightforward algorithm?

Comment: Oh, man, hashing might be difficult to implement. You know, committees consisting of many people work hard to invent a new hashing algorithm.

Comment: The best solution might be to use an existing hash, then implement a simple transformation into a form you like.

Comment: @ForceBru: Are you thinking of cryptographic hashes? Those take a lot of specialized expertise to do right, but non-cryptographic hashes are pretty straightforward. Also, there's no requirement that this hash be in any way a new invention.

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to generate unique, human-transcribable referral codes.  Something a customer could enter to claim a discount or similar.  And I want them to be (effectively) uniquely tied to the email address of the referrer.

Comment: Regarding kindall's suggestion: That could work, I think.  Generate a hexdigest hash, truncate, and then map groups of characters to  the desired subset?

Comment: @user2357112 Non cryptographic hashe many times allow for frequent collisions, I doubt that is what the OP wants. Examples are hashes used for dictinaries or storing bottles at clubs. When there is a collision either a re-hash or linerar search is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you should be using has similarities with password one-way encryption. Of course since you are going for readable, a good password function is probably out of the question.

Here's what I would do:

1. Take an MD5 hash of the email
2. Convert base32 which already eliminates O and I
3. Replace any non-readable characters with readable ones

Here's an example based on the above:

```
 import base64 # base32 is a function in base64
 import hashlib

 email = "somebody@example.com"

 md5 = hashlib.md5()
 md5.update(email.encode('utf-8'))

 hash_in_bytes = md5.digest()

 result = base64.b32encode(hash_in_bytes)

 print(result)

 # Or you can remove the extra "=" at the end

 result = result.strip(b'=')
```

Since it's a one-way function (hash), you obviously don't need to worry about reversing the process (you can't anyway). You can also replace any other characters you find non-readable with readable ones (I would go for lowercase versions of the characters, e.g. q instead of Q)

More about base32 here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Comment: With the added step of truncating the result to fewer (e.g. 7) characters, the above solution does what I need very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply truncate the beginning of an MD5sum algorithm. It should have approximately the same statistical properties than the whole string anyway:

```
import md5
m = md5.new()
m.update("arbitrary string")
print(m.hexdigest()[:7])
```

Same code with `hashlib` module:

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("arbitrary string")
print(m.hexdigest()[:7])
```